# How to implement cleveref's \cref@currentlabel correctly for custom cross-references

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I have some custom cross-references that need labels that are not naturally linked to counters.
My macros therefore set `\@currentlabel` directly instead of using `\refstepcounter`.
This works fine but `cleveref` is not able to understand the type of these references (unless one specifies a custom type for each affected `\label`).

I have seen questions where redefining `\cref@currentlabel` managed to get `cleveref` informed of the right format to use but it is not clear what is the arguments specification that the package is expecting to be used.
From bits and pieces, the redefinition seems to follow a scheme similar to

```
\protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
  [type][???][\cref@result]%
  The typeset label}
```

So my question is: how is one supposed to communicate to `cleveref` that the current label is a custom one, with custom type `mytype`?
How is `\cref@currentlabel` supposed to be redefined?

Comment: `cleverref` always complains about unknown types, i.e. the if you use `foo` as type, and do not specify the corresponding `\crefformat{foo}{#2#1#3}` it will choke otherwise your approach should work

Comment: I think the crucial point is the macro ` \cref@constructprefix{#1}{\cref@result}`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer it's ok if I need to instruct cleveref on how to handle the custom type. My issue is: how to signal which type I want it to use, if I am bypassing `\refstepcounter`?

Comment: I have no fully working solution yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cleveref` is a very clever package, but hard to understand as it has many windings inside.

The easiest way, in my point of view, is to use `\label[type]{labelname}`
Funny enough, `type` does not need to be a counter at all, but `\cref@currentlabel` must be defined as has been done by the O.P. already.

The value in the second `[...]` inside of the `\cref@currentlabel{...}` has usually the value of the counter, this is not important here, so I left it empty.

The `\crefname` and `\Crefname` macros should be called to inform `cleveref` about the `type name`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\usepackage{xparse}


\makeatletter

\NewDocumentCommand{\arblabel}{O{footext}m+m}{%
  \begingroup
  \cref@constructprefix{#1}{\cref@result}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
    #3}%
  \protected@edef\@currentlabelname{#3}%
  \protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{%
    [#1][][\cref@result]%
    #3%
  }
  \label[#1]{#2}%
  \endgroup  
}

\makeatother


\crefname{footext}{some foo text}{some foo texts}
\Crefname{footext}{Some Foo text}{Some foo texts}


\begin{document}

\blindtext[3]
\section{My section} \label{secone}
\blindtext[2]

Here is the link target: \arblabel{foo}{This is a nice foo text}

\blindtext[2]

\cref{foo} or rather like \Cref{foo}?

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.
Followup question: is the value of the counter (left empty here) used for sorting? Would this create unwanted effects when using `\cref{foo1,foo2}`? And what does `\cref@result` do? And `constructprefix`?

Comment: @Bordaigorl: I have to check...

Comment: I guess you want a `\phantomsection` too?

Comment: It is a pity that this is not documented, cleveref is such a nice package...

Comment: @Bordaigorl: I am not sure, most likely

Comment: @Bordaigorl: Yes, the code is hard to read, in my point of view

Comment: `\cref{foo1,foo2}` seems to work...

Comment: @Christian Hupfer's solution looks OK to me. It can be simplified a bit. There's no need (or point) to set the prefix data - it can safely be left empty, like the counter value. These are only used for sorting and compression, which anyway can't be done with these custom, non-counter-based cross-references. (In fact, the code in this solution will always produce empty prefix data anyway.) Cleveref will cope gracefully when this data is missing - it'll leave the references in the order given, and won't compress them.

Comment: So the \arblabel definition could be simplified to just:

\protected@edef\cref@currentlabel{[#1][][]#3}%
\label[#1]{#2}%

Comment: @Bordaigorl the format of \cref@currentlabel isn't documented because it's an internal implementation detail that could be (and has) changed. There's no guarantee this solution will work in all future cleveref versions.